# c++ decltype(auto) or decltype(std::forward<T>(value))?

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, decltype

For example, simple identity functor:

```
template <typename T>
class identity
{
public:
    constexpr auto operator ()(T && i) -> decltype(std::forward<T>(i))
    {
        return std::forward<T>(i);
    }
};
```

What is better (C++14 and newer) for return value:

- `-> decltype(std::forward<T>(i))` or
- `-> decltype(auto)`

Or are they the same?

Comment: You can just have `auto` with no `-> decltype`

Comment: Or if you insist on `decltype` semantics, just `decltype(auto)`.

Comment: @JakeFreeman that would have value semantics

Comment: `decltype(auto) operator () ...` is also valid.

Comment: BTW, you should know `i` is not a forwarding reference. So that's also something to consider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or are they the same?

Assuming you write it correctly:

```
constexpr decltype(auto) operator ()(T && i)
{
    return std::forward<T>(i);
}
```

They are the same. [[dcl.type.auto.deduct]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.auto.deduct):

> A type `T` containing a placeholder type, and a corresponding
>   initializer `e`, are determined as follows:
>
> - for a non-discarded return statement that occurs in a function declared with a return type that contains a placeholder type, **`T` is the
>     declared return type and `e` is the operand of the return statement**. If
>     the return statement has no operand, then `e` is `void()`;
>
> If the placeholder is the `decltype(auto)` type-specifier, `T` shall be
>   the placeholder alone. The type deduced for `T` is determined as
>   described in [dcl.type.simple], as though `e` had been the operand of
>   the `decltype`

The return type of the function is deduced from `return e;` as though by `decltype(e)`. So it would be the same as an explicit `decltype(std::forward<T>(i))`.

> What is better

In this case, I'll go with "less is more". `decltype(auto)` gives you what you are after with less verbosity.

Comment: What about `-> T&&`?

Comment: @cpplearner - Would also work for a forwarding reference (which the OP doesn't have), due to reference collapsing. You should post it as an answer (maybe even mention the OP not having a forwarding ref). I'm too tired